# How to multiply matrix of nxm with matrix nxmxp different dimensions in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, multiplication, matrix-inverse

In my current analysis, I am trying to multiply a matrix (flm), of dimension *nxm*, with the inverse of a matrix *nxmxp*, and then use this result to multiply it by the inverse of the matrix (flm).

I was trying using the following code:

```
flm = repmat(Data.fm.flm(chan,:),[1 1 morder]); %chan -> is a vector 1by3
A = (flm(:,:,:)/A_inv(:,:,:))/flm(:,:,:);
```

However. due to the problem of dimensions, I am getting  the following error message:
Error using ==> mrdivide
Inputs must be 2-D, or at least one
input must be scalar.
To compute elementwise RDIVIDE, use
RDIVIDE (./) instead.

I have no idea on how to proceed without using a *for* loop, so anyone as any suggestion?

Comment: P.S. I copy one thing wrong (the second flm doesn't have parameters) so it suposed to look like this:

                        flm = repmat(Data.fm.flm(chan,:),[1 1 morder]);
                        A = (flm(:,:,:)/A_inv(:,:,:))/flm(:,:,:);

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note that you can edit your own question by clicking the "edit" button below the question. Also, it's nice if you try to format the code as nice as you can (for instance not having 27 spaces in front of the code).

Comment: How do you calculate the inverse of a 3D-matrix? That's not possible. Are each of the 2D-slices inverted separately? Also, why calculate the (undefined) inverse of A and use division, instead of just multiplying it?

Comment: I don't want to invert the 3D matrix, what I need is to inverse each layer of the matrix A_inv (yes each 2D-slices is inverted seperatly) and then multiply it by the Data.fm.flm matrix (which is _2by2_ ). The name _A_inv_ is so I can know that the matrix I got (earlier in the program )is not yet the matrix A but an inversion matrix of the one I want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a way to conveniently multiply matrices when one is of higher dimensionality than the other. In that case you can use `bxsfun` to automatically 'expand' the smaller matrix.

```
x  = rand(3,4);
y = rand(3,4,5);
bsxfun(@times,x,y)
```

It is quite simple, and very efficient.

Make sure to check out `doc bsxfun` for more examples.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. However, I was checking and the following code doesn't give me the same result: 

x  = rand(3,3);
y = rand(3,3,5);
test1 = bsxfun(@times,x,y)

for i = 1 :size(y,3)
test2 = x*y(:,:,i);
end;

why is that? Do you know?
Is it beacause the bsxfun '[...] applies an element-by-element binary operation to arrays A and B [...]', if so How can I solve my problem using algebra rulls for matrix multiplication?

Comment: @tTimoteof, the same result as what exactly?

Comment: @tTimoteof It indeed does the element by element multiplication. If you want the regular matrix multiplication, I would just go for the single loop you mention in your comment. Just make sure the result matrix does not grow during the loop.

Comment: Ok thankyou for the sugestion, then I think the loop will be the best option. @RobertP. The same result in terms of final matrix, because one those the _element by element_ multiplication and the other does it by _matrix rules of multiplication_